# Line Plot Function in Python Panel Not Working

Tags: python, panel

I am trying to make a function that when called displays a line plot comparing the crash year to the number of persons of injured, killed, etc (depending on what the user may select). I am not able to figure out what is wrong with my function currently:

```
dropdown_columns = ['NUMBER OF PERSONS INJURED', 'NUMBER OF PERSONS KILLED', 
                    'NUMBER OF PEDESTRIANS INJURED', 'NUMBER OF PEDESTRIANS KILLED', 
                    'NUMBER OF CYCLIST INJURED', 'NUMBER OF CYCLIST KILLED', 
                    'NUMBER OF MOTORIST INJURED', 'NUMBER OF MOTORIST KILLED']


dropdown = pn.widgets.Select(name='Select', options = dropdown_columns)

def linePlot(chosen):
    return df[dropdown_columns == chosen].hvplot('CRASH_YEAR', dropdown_columns)

interact(linePlot, chosen= dropdown)
```

However, this causes the following error when 'interact(linePlot, chosen= dropdown)' is run:
ValueError('A function cannot have "throttled" as an argument') and
"""
258     Return an interactive function widget for the given function.
259     The widget is only constructed, not displayed nor attached to
(...)
267         The function to which the interactive widgets are tied.
268     """

I wanted the y-axis of the line-plot to be the number of persons affected by the crash. So, I set the y-axis to dropdown_columns so that the line polot will change accordingly. I can't seem to figure out what is causing the errors.